# c++ is there a way of use properties allready declared in the header file inside implementation

Tags: c++, oop, precompiled-headers

I know it's a basic question, but I didn't find the answer anywhere.

Supose we have this header:

```
#pragma once;
#include "user.h"

class Teacher
{
public:
    float teachSkill = 0.01;
    void teach(User &user);
};
```

And a implementation like this:

```
#include "teacher.h"

class Teacher
{
public:
    float teachSkill;
    void teach(User &user)
    {
        user.knowledge += (*this).teachSkill;
    }
};
```

if we already declared that `teachSkill` property in the header, is there a way c++ compiler can understand that this property is in the header on an implementation like this:

```
#include "teacher.h"

class Teacher
{
public:
    void teach(User &user)
    {
        user.knowledge += (*this).teachSkill;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your implementation is redefining the `Teacher` class. 

At compile time, the contents of the header are essentially copy-pasted at the `#include` statement. 

I'm not entirely sure what your question is

Comment: This is not how you define class methods in .cpp file, please get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from. C++ can't be learned by trial and error.

Comment: You have defined the class `Teacher` twice, and the definitions are different.  That breaks a rule known as the "one definition rule" - and doing so causes undefined behaviour.  In the implementation file, only `#include "teacher.h"` and define its member function (in a way consistent with the declaration in the header) as something like `void Teacher::teach(User user) { .....}`.    If you want that function to be able to modify the object passed by the caller as `user` change both the declaration (in the class definition) AND the implementation of the function so the argument is `User &user`

Comment: Note that `#pragma once` is not standard C++ and never will be; there are build environments where it cannot be implemented correctly. Portable code uses include guards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write, in the implementation:

```
void Teacher::teach(User &user)
{
    user.knowledge += (*this).teachSkill;
}
```

No need to re-declare the class there.

Furthermore, you don't need `(*this)`, so it's simply:

```
void Teacher::teach(User &user)
{
    user.knowledge += teachSkill;
}
```

Comment: You might want to address the fact that, in the header file, `Teacher::teach()` accepts its argument by value, but you are defining that same function to accept argument by reference.    Otherwise your answer is incomplete (and probably misleading for a beginner, as in this case, who doesn't appear to understand the distinction between pass by value and pass by reference).

Comment: I edited the question to make the header method file use the reference.

Comment: @Peter OP fixed that, it was more likely a typo.